# The King's March

Tags: dynamic, dynamic-programming

You’re given a chess board with dimension n x n. There’s a king at the bottom right square of the board marked with s. The king needs to reach the top left square marked with e. The rest of the squares are labeled either with an integer p (marking a point) or with x marking an obstacle. Note that the king can move up, left and up-left (diagonal) only. Find the maximum points the king can collect and the number of such paths the king can take in order to do so.

Input Format
The first line of input consists of an integer t. This is the number of test cases. Each test case contains a number n which denotes the size of board. This is followed by n lines each containing n space separated tokens.

Output Format
For each case, print in a separate line the maximum points that can be collected and the number of paths available in order to ensure maximum, both values separated by a space. If e is unreachable from s, print 0 0.

Sample Input

```
3
3
e 2 3
2 x 2
1 2 s
3
e 1 2
1 x 1
2 1 s
3
e 1 1
x x x
1 1 s
```

Sample Output

```
7 1
4 2
0 0
```

Constraints
1 <= t <= 100

2 <= n <= 200

1 <= p <= 9

Comment: Do you have a *question*? This isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: i just want a logic

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem could be solved using dynamic-programing. We could use `dp[i,j]` to calculate the best number of points you can obtain by going from the right bottom corner to the `i,j` position. We can calculate `dp[i,j]`, for a valid `i,j`, based on `dp[i+1,j]`, `dp[i,j+1]` and `dp[i+1,j+1]` if this are valid positions(not out of the matrix or marked as `x`) and adding them the points obtained in the `i,j` cell. You should start computing from the bottom right corner to the left top, row by row and beginning from the last column.

For the number of ways you can add a new matrix `ways` and use it to store the number of ways.

This is an example code to show the idea:

```py
dp[i,j] = dp[i+1,j+1] + board[i,j]
ways[i,j] = ways[i+1,j+1]

if dp[i,j] < dp[i+1,j] + board[i,j]:
   dp[i,j] = dp[i+1,j] + board[i,j]
   ways[i,j] = ways[i+1,j]

elif dp[i,j] == dp[i+1,j] + board[i,j]:
   ways[i,j] += ways[i+1,j]

# check for i,j+1
```

This assuming all positions are valid.

The final result is stored in `dp[0,0]` and `ways[0,0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Brief Overview:
This problem can be solved through recursive method call, starting from n*n till it reaches 0*0 which is the king's destination.

For the detailed explanation and the solution for this problem,check it out here -> https://www.callstacker.com/detail/algorithm-1